# Printing corresponding CSV values using FOR loop

Tags: csv, for-loop, input, indexing

This is my first post here, and I'm a bit lost on this scenario since I'm new to loops. I'm being asked to write a program that takes an integer input, and uses that input to print out the corresponding values on a CSV/Excel list. I was able to get to a point where it printed both the names and values based on the input, but the formatting is not the right way I need it to be, and my script is a bit clunky.

Specifically, I have to print states and populations. If I put in 5, it will print out both the names and populations from 0 to 5.

I can't use Pandas, as I'm still a beginner, and this is for a course.

This is where I am.

```py
    print('Give me a number thats 0 - 50:')
    user_num = int(input())
    for name in state_names:
        if name == state_names[user_num]:
            names = state_names[0:user_num]
    for pop in state_populations:
        if pop == state_populations[user_num]:
            pops = state_populations[0:user_num]
    print(f'{names}, {pops}')
```

If the input was 3, the output comes out to:

```
['Michigan', 'Georgia', 'Ohio'], [9986857, 10617423, 11689100]
```

instead of

```
Michigan   9986857
Georgia   10617423
Ohio      11689100
```

which is the output I need.

What can I do to shorten it and make it produce that output?

Comment: You can either print the state-name and -population when the if-statement is true, or traverse the list at the end.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you can use `zip()` function:

```py
state_names = ['Michigan', 'Georgia', 'Ohio', 'New York']
state_populations = [9986857, 10617423, 11689100, 99999]

print('Give me a number:')
user_num = int(input())

for n, p in zip(state_names[:user_num], state_populations[:user_num]):
    print(f'{n:<10} {p:>10}')
```

Prints:

```
Give me a number:
3
Michigan      9986857
Georgia      10617423
Ohio         11689100
```